# TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'renderRows'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have the following package.json settings.  Everything is ok when I do 'ng serve'.  However, when I run my application, my mat-table won't load and in the console, it says "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'renderRows'".  I saw in one post that it's due to cdk version.  But it's already 5.2.5.  Please advise.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.13.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
```

Comment: Is this issue on IE11?

Answer (score 0):

It's ok now, I mistakenly added the 'dataTable' from

`@ViewChild('dataTable') dataTable: MatTable<Test>;`

to the wrong div. I moved it to `<mat-table>`.